# How do you provide JSON response data in .NET?

Tags: .net, ajax, json, response.write

Without using any third party tools, what is the ideal way to provide JSON response data?

I was thinking of having an ASPX application page to just return the json string response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a method with the `[WebMethod]` attribute, and the response will automatically be JSON serialized. Try it yourself:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDateTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

And the Ajax call URL would be:

```
Page.aspx/GetDateTime
```

#### Edit:

To pass parameters, just add them to the function:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int AddNumbers(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

I'm using jQuery so the `data:` object would be set with:

```
data: "{n1: 1, n2: 2}",
```

Also note that the JSON object returned will look like this:

```
{"d":[3]}
```

The extra `"d"` in the data is explained here: http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: how would you pass params tho?

Answer (score 8):

Not an aspx page, but maybe an ashx handler.  To make this easier, .Net 3.5 has [serialization support for JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx) built in.

Comment: Because you don't need the full page lifecycle.  An aspx page will cause of bunch of work to happen you don't need - it's wasteful.

Comment: +1 - This is definitely worth noting if he's doing several requests to the same function

Comment: Hmm... my basic text is right, but my link might be for the wrong json serializer.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the JavascriptSerializer class that is provided by the ASP.NET framework.  Generally you would use this in a Page Method or a WebMethod in a WebService to return an object serialized as JSON.

See the reference on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a web service (asmx) with the ScriptService attribute and ScriptManager. There are some slight incompatibilities with some jQuery plugins, but it's nothing too serious and I don't have to deal with any manual serialization.